# How to add onclick event in cakephp submit button?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to add onclick event in cakephp submit button.But this is not working.Here is my code.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit',array('onclick'=>'myfunc()'))); ?>
```

How can I add javascript event in submit button ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'label' => 'Submit',
    'id' => 'submit',
    'onclick' => 'myfunc()'
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
?>
```

Comment: you can remove id if you don't need it.